# Unable to open terminal & File Manager in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: command-line, nautilus

Too descriptive question, please bear with me. Thank you
I'm using Dell Atitude E7440, which has ubuntu 18.04. The alt+ctl+t is not opening any terminal & clicking on "File Manager"(keeps on loading near Activities bar for few seconds) as well is not opening any window. I opened VS code and from there, I am able to access my terminal. So far, I have checked if there are any broken packages which seems of no issue. I have reinstalled nautilus & it didn't help. When I try to right click on desktop & open terminal , it as well is not opening window for terminal. Strange thing after I restarted laptop ,(File Manager broke, terminal broke & Chrome asking for password out of nowhere)
Please help me to open the nautilas & terminal.

I'm able to open nautilus from VS Code terminal using-

```
sudo nautilus

Called "net usershare info" but it failed: Failed to execute child process “net” (No such file or directory)
```

Within Nautilus, I see two new mounted devices on the left side (efi & the loaded drive to the laptop)[image]

Thank you

Comment: It may sound weird, but go into your systems settings and reapply the language settings. And let us know if this fixed it for you.

Comment: I did go through the language settings earlier as mentioned in one of the forums. But it didn't help :(

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same symptoms and resolved this. Please correct me in the comments if I am writing something wrong because I am new to OS in general.

Tl;dr

> I have changed my password and everything got back to normal

It all started when I have established a connection using noMachine from a remote PC. My guess is, that due to enabling noMachine to remember my user and password for future login I have somehow enabled the automatic login on the Ubuntu host.

As a result, each time I logged in, the system did not recognize me as an admin without typing my password for each operation. This is demonstrated by a popup massage:

> Enter password to unlock your login keyring
>   The login keyring did not get unlocked when you logged into your computer
>   which appears on opening chrome after a reboot.

Also, you gave a hint when you stated that "I'm able to open nautilus from VS Code terminal using- `sudo nautilus`". I proceeded to use xterm for the same results as well as launching gnome-terminal successfully using `sudo gnome-terminal` from xterm.

So something is definetely wrong with explaining my self as an admin to my OS. In short, a simple password change saved the day and I am refraining from autologing in with noMachine. I am sure that all Ubuntu experts here will be able to explain what happened better than me, so go ahead and comment. I will edit this answer accordingly if needed.